# Preventing styles of html elements created by firefox plugin getting overridden by the sites stylesheet

Tags: css, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk

I am injecting some html + css into every page from my firefox plugin. But this styles is sometimes getting overridden by the style sheet. I want to stop this behavior.

I know this can be solved by some css tricks. Adding `!important` for instance. But is there a way available in firefox or xul to do this easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `!important` alone is not enough, the webpage could do the same and still override your styls. You can [use the Stylesheet Service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Stylesheet_Service) to register a user stylesheet. If you then use `!important` then web pages will no longer be able to override your styles.

Note that user stylesheets are always global and apply to all webpages as well as browser's own XUL documents. You can restrict them to particular webpages using [@-moz-document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@-moz-document).

Comment: Will this cause any problem while submitting my plugin to firefox?

Comment: Why should it? It's the approach used by various add-on, most importantly Stylish.

Comment: @WladimirPalant What about for attributes not specified in my CSS? If I have a `textarea` with a specified `height` of `20px` and no `min-height`, but the page has `textarea {min-height: 40px}`, my height is overridden. I understand that I can set the `min-height` attribute, but setting every possible attribute for every injected HTML element doesn't seem like a good solution. Any ideas?

Comment: @willlma: There is no way around it, you have to set all the relevant CSS properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
#MEGA_PLUNGIN a {}
#MEGA_PLUNGIN span {}
#MEGA_PLUNGIN div {}
#MEGA_PLUNGIN table {}
...
```

Not the best solution but right...

Answer (score 0):

To me, this is one case where you would certainly use `!important`.

That said, you can try to use specificity to ensure your styles are being set.

So, make sure that you are targeting the elements are precisely as possible, in order to override those styles that are not as specific.

For instance, if you have this structure

```
<body>
    <div>
        <h1 class="something">
            <a href>
```

The site's styles may target

```
h1.something a{
```

You should aim to do this

```
body div h1.something a{
```

which is more specific and would override the above styles.

The other thing you might be able to do is `append` your styles just before the `</head>`, which would make them appear last in the cascade, and, if they are equal, will be applied.